# remove just 'UTC' text at the end from DateTime stamp

Tags: javascript, datetime, utc

I am using `date.toGMTString()` to get `DateTime` as GMT standrad. so what I am getting is `'Fri, 26 Apr 2013 17:08:35 UTC'` this. I just want to display this without the text `'UTC'`. please let me know

Comment: `date.toGMTString().substr(0, 25)`

Answer (score 7):

Use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice):

```
date.toGMTString().slice(0, -4)
```

Btw, you should notice that [`toGMTString` is deprecated and the same as `toUTCString`](http://es5.github.io/#B.2.6), and that the method does return an *implementation-dependent* human-readable UTC date string. You cannot be sure that it ends with `" UTC"` (or `" GMT"`), so you rather might use

```
date.toUTCString().replace(/\s*(GMT|UTC)$/, "")
```

Comment: But if they both end in 4 characters you don't want, doesn't that make `slice` just as dependent? Or is there a possibility it doesn't end with anything extra?

Comment: Yes, it would be possible that there is no extra (or that the timezone denotation is somewhere else in the string, or…)

Answer (score 2):

`toGMTString()` is **[deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toGMTString)**... Use `toUTCString()` instead...

```
date.toUTCString().slice(0, -4)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var d= new Date();

d=d.toLocaleString(); 

//Converts a Date object to a string, using locale conventions
//hence the UTC or GMT+.. is removed
```

Answer (score 1):

For ultimate in formatting options and cross-browser consistency, use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

```
var m = moment(date);
var s = m.format('ddd, D MMM YYYY H:mm:ss');
```

See [the docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) for other format strings, including localizable ones.